# Rails how to make tags in Product model by categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models Product(title, description, category_id) and Category(title, description).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
```

Now product can have only one category and it's working perfectly, but i want to make, that Product can have one more categories like tags, but i can't understand how..

Comment: please clarify yourself, would you like your products to belong to multiple categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the has_and_belongs_to_many association
[documented here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

edit: ok you asked for quick example

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

migrations

```
create_table :categories do |t|
  t.string :title
  ...

create_table :products do |t|
  t.string :title
  ...

create_table :categories_products, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :category, index: true
  t.belongs_to :product, index: true
end
```

you can than access a products categories

```
Product.find(1).categories
```